# FOS UserBundle Access Denied

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, rights

I'm trying to use FOS UserBundle to manage users on my project.

Here is my **security.yml** file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I have manually set my user's rights in my controller like below :

```
public function testGroupsAction( UserInterface $user )
    {
        $user->addRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        echo "<pre>";
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($user->getRoles());
        echo "</pre>";die;
    }
```

the $user->getRoles() function returns me an array with all my user's roles :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' (length=16)
  1 => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
  2 => string 'ROLE_USER' (length=9)
```

(ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN has been added during my tests)

However when i try to reach a route like "/admin/my/route"n i've got a 403 access forbidden.

Any idea why Symfony doesn't want my user to access admin pages?

Edit :

When i look in the profiler, the user only has [ROLE_USER]...

Thank you.

Comment: when you are setting user roles ? symfony2 security system may be looking at your user roles before you set them.

Comment: I set them in my controller testGroupsAction : I add the "ROLE_ADMIN" to my $user and then save it into my database. When i get my User object back, i have this "ROLE_ADMIN" when I use the $user->getRoles() (look at my var_dump).

So if the security system checks my user's roles, it should get my newly added one right?

I edited my post with the profiler data. Hope it helps.

Comment: I doubt that you have problem in adding roles since in profiler only `ROLE_USER` is there. try adding role admin with command line and see what happends https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md#4-promote-a-user

Comment: @zizoujab FOSUserBundle automatically uses `ROLE_USER` when no role is defined. I guess It wasn't the way to add a role : the CLI command worked perfectly, so i tried to use the UserManipulator that is used in the PromoteUserCommand and it worked. I responded to my post below :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Had you logged out and back in again? The roles are set for your user from the database when the user first logs in so unless to reset the token, either by logging out and then in again or by setting a new token in the security context, then your roles will be the same as they first were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working.

Thanks to Zizoujab, I tried FOSUserBundle's commands to promote a user :

```
> php app/console fos:user:promote myUser
```

It worked perfectly well. However, as I have no ssh access nor any other command line tool on my server, i needed to do it via PHP code.

So i went to the Command code FOS\UserBundle\Command\PromoteUserCommand which uses the FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator to do actions on the user.

So if you want to modify your User directly in your controller, you can use it, but I don't know if it is the best way to do it. Just call it via your container like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/{id}", name="test_user")
 * @ParamConverter("user" , class="MyBundle:User")
 */
public function testUserAction( UserInterface $user )
{
    $userManipulator = $this->container->get("fos_user.util.user_manipulator");
    $userManipulator->addRole($user,'ROLE_ADMIN');

    return new Response();
}
```

Hope it helps.